# Swift "Reference Cycles for Closures" Question(s)

Tags: swift, memory-management, closures

I wanted to experiment some with closure cycles in Swift. So I started with a playground and the [example in the Swift documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ID56).

```
class HTMLElement {
    let name: String
    let text: String?

    lazy var asHTML: () -> String = {
        if let text = self.text {
            return "<\(self.name)>\(text)</\(self.name)>"
        } else {
            return "<\(self.name) />"
        }
    }

    init(name: String, text: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
    }

    deinit {
        print("\(name) is being deinitialized")
    }
}

var element = HTMLElement(name: "Travis", text: "Griggs")
print(element.asHTML()) // force the cycle
element = HTMLElement(name: "Bat", text: "Man") // encourage first element to deallocate
```

As expected, no hint of `deinit` because of the cycle. I can break the cycle if I just initialize `asHTML` to be a closure that doesn't capture self. E.g.

```
var element = HTMLElement(name: "Travis", text: "Griggs")
element.asHTML = { "No Cycles Here" }
print(element.asHTML()) // do the print
element = HTMLElement(name: "Bat", text: "Man") // encourage first element to deallocate
```

OR I can change the `asHTML` default initialization to include:

```
{ [ weak self] in
    guard let self = self else { return "-from-the-dead-" }
    ...
}
```

Also does the right thing. But an approach that I thought would work, does not seem to. Many of my closures often just look like

```
{ self.doSomething() }
```

where `doSomething` basically has the same signature as the closure signature. In that case, it seems that the closure is just an extra wrapper. Imagine if I add a method to `HTMLElement` which has the `() -> String` signature:

```
extension HTMLElement {
    func defaultHTML() -> String {
        return "\(self.name) = \(self.text ?? "(there is no text)")"
    }
}
```

and then set the `asHTML` property directly to that:

```
var element = HTMLElement(name: "Travis", text: "Griggs")
element.asHTML = element.defaultHTML
print(element.asHTML())
element = HTMLElement(name: "Bat", text: "Man") // encourage first element to deallocate
```

For some reason, I though that this would not create a cycle. But I appear to be wrong? `element` does NOT `deinit`. It's a bit counterintuitive because I didn't use braces to make a closure. But it appears to that referencing a method of a live instance does exactly that? Is that what is going on? Assuming that there's not another explanation, is there a way to break the cycle in this case? Or do I always need to be explicit about my closures with something like:

```
element.asHTML = { [weak element] in element?.defaultHTML() ?? "-yo-text-be-gone-" }
```

Comment: A method and a closure are (in most senses) the same thing, so when you store the function as a variable you are capturing self.defaultHTML (just as if you were referencing a class-level property) and creating another reference in ARC.  This screws with my head too, and I can usually convince myself both ways and have to do the deinit test too :-). I like this for a reference: https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/weak-self/

Comment: "So I started with a playground" Not the issue at hand here, but generally, don't do that. Playgrounds make references of your objects for visualization purposes. They're not a reliable depiction of ARC behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

`defaultHTML()` isn't just a function, and it's instance method. It's operates on an instance, in your case, `self`. Your closure can't just remember "just call `defaultHTML`" without also remembering which instance to call it on.

So when you create a closure like `{ self.defaultHTML }`, you're creating a heap allocated, ARC-managed box, which contains a strong reference to `self`, and a pointer to the `defaultHTML` instance method's implementation.

Comment: Yes, I intimated that I suspected that's what's happening. And it makes sense. The question, is it the exact same machinery? Or something similar but different. And more important, if one wants to use this technique to reduce boilerplate typing, is there a way to break the cycle? There's no where to tune the capture nature of the instance-relative function that I see.

Comment: "The question, is it the exact same machinery?" as compared to what? "to reduce boilerplate typing, is there a way to break the cycle?" Nope. Your approach of capturing `self` weakly, and conditionally unwrapping it upon invocation of the closure is the correct approach currently.